# set samba permission on create new file

Tags: centos, samba

I have a centos share folder that is shared whit these specific

```
[share]
    path = /mnt/share
    force user = winuser
    force group = winuser
    guest only = yes
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    writable = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0777
    force create mask = 0777
    directory mask = 0777
    force directory mode = 0777
```

When a samba client (windows) uses the 'winuser' account to create a file or directory, the permissions become

```
-rw-rw---- 1 winuser winuser
```

Why doesn't samba set the correct permissions? What I'm wrong?

Comment: +FireFoxII Do you know anything about this? - [INTERNAL LINK: unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592705/how-to-change-permissions-and-access-on-a-samba-network-share-hosted-on-centos7)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the mask for your group `winuser`(the group of the user winuser):

```
winuser mask = 0777
force winuser mode = 0777    
directory winuser mask = 0777
force directory winuser mode = 0777
```

Comment: Not working, same problem....